# cel-go. how to use custom objects and timestamp comparisons

Tags: go

I am using Google/cel-go library for conditional evaluation purposes.
Here's a scenario I'm trying to accomplish.
I have a struct say user.
It has a expirydate field which contains string timestamp.
I want to compare that against current system timestamp.
I'm trying to figure out how to do that with cel-go. Could someone help.
Also I have a bunch of other fields in my user struct which I would use to construct more expressions. How can I use my struct as input to use user.fieldname notation

Answer (score 2):

[CEL](https://github.com/google/cel-spec) is a C-like expression language where the expression can only referenced variables, functions, and macros that the host process exposes. CEL provides a library of builtin functions, or you can supply your own custom functions.

Given the following expression:

```
user.expirydate > now
```

The host process must declare the following variables:

```
user // type DYN
now  // type TIMESTAMP
```

All operators are declared as functions within CEL and which ones are supported in a given expression is customizable. The `>` operator is one of the standard builtins, so it's available by default.

The following is an example of how you might parse, type-check, and evaluate the example. Type-checking is optional, but strongly encouraged since it ensures the variables and functions are being used correctly.

```
vars := cel.Declarations(
   decls.NewIdent('user', decls.Dyn, nil),
   decls.NewIdent('now', decls.Timestamp, nil),
)
// The err and iss values should be checked, but for brevity the checks
// have been omitted.
env, err     := cel.NewEnv(vars)
parsed, iss  := env.Parse(`user.expirydate > now`)
ast, iss     := env.Check(parsed)
program, err := env.Program(ast)

// The data is a map containing the desired fields.
// The result contains the outcome of evaluation.
result, details, err := program.Eval(data)
```

Working [Go Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/-IsfIbahvot).

Note, evaluation is mutation free and side-effect free which means that extension functions must be idempotent. If the `now` were replaced with a function `now()` the expectation is that the function would behave like a lazy attribute which computes the time once and returns the same value for the duration of the expression.

```
// now() must return the same value on both invocations.
user.expirydate > now() && user.expirydate < now() - duration('300s')
```

For more detailed examples, I would recommend looking at the conformance tests within the [google/cel-spec](https://github.com/google/cel-spec) repository and at the [godoc examples](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/cel-go/cel#example-package) for the [google/cel-go](https://github.com/google/cel-go) repo.